# Add and delete rows at run time

Tags: components, c++builder, vcl

I am working with C++ builder making VCL form application.

I am pretty new at this, and right now I'm trying to look for a component that allows me to make a table and have it show certain rows by default, but it also needs to allow me to add and delete rows during run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `Table`, do you just want a grid component for arbitrary app data, or do you want something that displays data from a database table?

If the former, use `TStringGrid`, or `TListView` with its `ViewStyle` property set to `vsReport`, or the third party [`TVirtualTreeView`](http://www.soft-gems.net).

If the latter, use `TDBGrid`.

Comment: i ended up using TStringGird and it's working pretty well. just some minor functions i need to figure out. thank you